# Cast array items to a object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data from a request

```
{
  id: '60c0ae7efebdca1288045337',
  name: 'Pepino Japonês',
  image: 'pepino-japones.png',
  saleUnit: [ 'g', 'Kg' ],
  price: [ 'R$ 2,50', 'R$ 5,50' ],
  description: [ 'undefined', 'Descrição' ],
  active: [ '0', '1' ],
  category: 'Verduras'
}
```

I need to cast the content of the arrays saleUnit, price, description and active to a object saleUnits like this.

```
{
  id: '60c0ae7efebdca1288045337',
  name: 'Pepino Japonês',
  image: 'pepino-japones.png',
  saleUnits:[ 
              {saleUnit: 'g', price: 2.50, description: 'undefined', active: 0}, 
              {saleUnit: 'kg', price: 5.50, description: 'Descrição', active: 1}, 
            ],
  category: 'Verduras'
}
```

What's the best aproach to this?.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67977871/edit) your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Use a for loop to create the new array combining array rows from each original column.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to be more specific next time. this time, already get a answer, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good approach.

```js
const a = {
  id: '60c0ae7efebdca1288045337',
  name: 'Pepino Japonês',
  image: 'pepino-japones.png',
  saleUnit: [ 'g', 'Kg' ],
  price: [ 'R$ 2,50', 'R$ 5,50' ],
  description: [ 'undefined', 'Descrição' ],
  active: [ '0', '1' ],
  category: 'Verduras'
}

const b = {
  id: a.id,
  name: a.name,
  image: a.image,
  category: a.category,
  saleUnits: a.saleUnit.map((unit, i) => ({
    saleUnit: unit,
    price: Number(a.price[i].replace('R$ ', '').replace(',','.')),
    description: a.description[i],
    active: Number(a.active[i])
  }))
}

console.log(b)
```

Comment: You nailed it @Lrazerz, work's  very well, just need a little twik on regex, but you save my day.